# Best practices for a class with many members

Tags: c++, parameters

Any opinions on best way to organize members of a class (esp. when there are many) in C++. In particular, a class has lots of user parameters, e.g. a class that optimizes some function and has number of parameters such as # of iterations, size of optimization step, specific method to use, optimization function weights etc etc. I've tried several general approaches and seem to always find something non-ideal with it. Just curious others experiences.

1. struct within the class
2. struct outside the class
3. public member variables
4. private member variables with Set() & Get() functions

To be more concrete, the code I'm working on tracks objects in a sequence of images. So one important aspect is that it needs to preserve state between frames (why I didn't just make a bunch of functions). Significant member functions include initTrack(), trackFromLastFrame(), isTrackValid(). And there are a bunch of user parameters (e.g. how many points to track per object tracked, how much a point can move between frames, tracking method used etc etc)

Comment: What do you mean by parameters of a class?  Members?  Template parameters?  Something else?

Comment: If it has *that* many members your class does too much, refactor your code.

Comment: You talk about a class, but you seem to be describing a function. :-/

Comment: Interesting questions but it would help if you provided a more concrete example maybe. Like relations between the members maybe. I could see that it could be useful to pack them all in a struct to simplify parameter passing during construction for example. Do you think you could post some code?

Comment: I have class called GraphicsVertex and have 5 member variable(Pointers). When my application runs it creates about 50 million objects. Now for each object it will hold 5 member * 50 Mn memory. How can i avoid it.

Answer (score 6):

If your class is **BIG**, then your class is **BAD**.
A class should respect the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) , i.e. : A class should do only one thing, but should do it well. (Well "only one" thing is extreme, but it should have only one role, and it has to be implemented clearly).

Then you create classes that you enrich by composition with those single-role little classes, each one having a clear and simple role.

BIG functions and BIG classes are nest for bugs, and misunderstanding, and unwanted side effects, (especially during maintainance), because NO MAN can learn in minutes 700 lines of code.

So the policy for BIG classes is: Refactor, Composition with little classes targetting only at what they have do.

Comment: Having a lot of parameters doesn't mean the class is big.  The class might do one thing, but require many parameters.

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy , I will answer you just a quotation: "If your function takes 10 parameters, you have most probably forgotten one".

Comment: but I agree with you, as long as it does one precise role.

Answer (score 3):

if i had to choose one of the four solutions you listed: private class within a class.

in reality: you probably have duplicate code which should be reused, and your class should be reorganized into smaller, more logical and reusable pieces. as GMan said: refactor your code

Answer (score 3):

First, I'd partition the members into two sets:  (1) those that are internal-only use, (2) those that the user will tweak to control the behavior of the class.  The first set should just be private member variables.

If the second set is large (or growing and changing because you're still doing active development), then you might put them into a class or struct of their own.  Your main class would then have a two methods, `GetTrackingParameters` and `SetTrackingParameters`.  The constructor would establish the defaults.  The user could then call `GetTrackingParameters`, make changes, and then call `SetTrackingParameters`.  Now, as you add or remove parameters, your interface remains constant.

If the parameters are simple and orthogonal, then they could be wrapped in a struct with well-named public members.  If there are constraints that must be enforced, especially combinations, then I'd implement the parameters as a class with getters and setters for each parameter.

```
ObjectTracker tracker;  // invokes constructor which gets default params
TrackerParams params = tracker.GetTrackingParameters();
params.number_of_objects_to_track = 3;
params.other_tracking_option = kHighestPrecision;
tracker.SetTrackingParameters(params);
// Now start tracking.
```

If you later invent a new parameter, you just need to declare a new member in the TrackerParams and initialize it in ObjectTracker's constructor.

Comment: If I may engage in some necromancy: Do you mean by "orthogonal" in this context that one parameter does not influence any other parameter? And in the case of "simple and orthogonal" parameters "wrapped in a struct" --> this struct would still be accessible by `Get/SetParams` functions or would this struct be a public member of the `ObjectTracker` class?

Comment: @LCsa: Yeah, "orthogonal" probably wasn't the best word; "independent" probably would have been better.  If you can change any parameter to any value without having to adjust any other parameter, then there's not much point to having getters and setters, since there are no constraints or invariants to enforce.  By "wrapped in a struct," I meant a plain, C-style struct with just data members and no methods other than a default constructor.

Comment: Thank you! I found this thread and it came in handy, but I'm still thinking about how to design classes without the need for a quadrillion of getters and setters...

Answer (score 2):

It all depends:

1. An internal struct would only be useful if you need to organize VERY many items. And if this is the case, you ought to reconsider your design.
2. An external struct would be useful if it will be shared with other instances of the same or different classes. (A model, or data object class/struct might be a good example)
3. Is only ever advisable for trivial, throw-away code.
4. This is the standard way of doing things but it all depends on how you'll be using the class.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that (2) would actually be the `TrackerParams` class in Adrian McCarthy's response but defined outside of `ObjectTracker`?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this could be a job for a template, the way you described the usage.

```
template class FunctionOptimizer <typename FUNCTION, typename METHOD, 
    typename PARAMS>
```

for example, where `PARAMS` encapsulates simple optimization run parameters (# of iterations etc) and `METHOD` contains the actual optimization code. `FUNCTION` describes the base function you are targeting for optimization.

The main point is not that this is the 'best' way to do it, but that if your class is very large there are likely smaller abstractions within it that lend themselves naturally  to refactoring into a less monolithic structure.

However you handle this, you don't have to refactor all at once - do it piecewise, starting small, and make sure the code works at every step.  You'll be surprised how much better you quickly feel about the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any benefit whatsoever to making a separate structure to hold the parameters. The class is already a struct - if it were appropriate to pass parameters by a struct, it would also be appropriate to make the class members public.

There's a tradeoff between public members and Set/Get functions. Public members are a lot less boilerplate, but they expose the internal workings of the class. If this is going to be called from code that you won't be able to refactor if you refactor the class, you'll almost certainly want to use Get and Set.

Comment: I have class called GraphicsVertex and have 5 member variable(Pointers). When my application runs it creates about 50 million objects. Now for each object it will hold 5 member * 50 Mn memory. How can i avoid it.

Comment: @DigviJayPatil I don't know if there's any way at all to avoid it. And this is completely the wrong way to ask.

Comment: Should I ask a question or Is it okay to ask in comments ?

Comment: @DigviJayPatil if you have a question, you should ask a question. You will need to provide more details. You should also delete your comments here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the configuration options apply only to this class, use private variables that are manipulated by public functions with meaningful function names.  `SetMaxInteriorAngle()` is much better than `SetMIA()` or `SetParameter6()`.  Having getters and setters allows you to enforce consistency rules on the configuration, and can be used to compensate for certain amounts of change in the configuration interface.

If these are general settings, used by more than one class, then an external class would be best, with private members and appropriate functions.

Public data members are usually a bad idea, since they expose the class's implementation and make it impossible to have any guaranteed relation between them.  Walling them off in a separate internal struct doesn't seem useful, although I would group them in the list of data members and set them off with comments.